# WSO2 dynamically checking ESB Worker Node in a cluster

Tags: dynamic, wso2, load-balancing, wso2-esb

i m using WSO2 ESBs 4.8.1 configured in a cluster. I'm also using an ELB for loadbalancing all the cluster nodes.

In my project requirements i need to know any time how many esb nodes are attached to the elb, so how many nodes are joining the cluster. Is there the possibility to develop an application able to do that using wso2 api?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use HazelCast to implement this functionality. I have attached a sample pseudo code below.

```
// Get the hazel cast inatance.
HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
// Then get the cluster information from it.
hz.getCluster().getMembers ().size();
```

Comment: how could be a typical configuration of hazelcast client if i have a typical cluster configuration with WSO2 ELB (127.0.0.1) WORKER1 (127.0.0.2) WORKER2 (127.0.0.3) and where the cluster is exposed publically  on port 80?